# What is the longest a visitor can stay in Botswana?

Tags: visa-extensions, botswana

How long can a visitor stay in Botswana, holding a passport eligible for visa-free entry?  (And from a high income country.)

Despite some websites simply saying you can't stay past 90 days in a year, Botswana's government site does indicate the possibility of extending visitor stays past 90 days [here](https://www.gov.bw/immigration/extension-days-visit).

However, the information on that page is pretty minimal, and leaves some questions.

- **How many days can be requested in a single application?**
- **Is there a maximum total duration they won't extend beyond in practice?**  (By "in practice", I'm referring to the situation in some countries where the law books technically have a certain limit but the offices usually don't enforce it if they don't suspect you of working in the country.)
- **How liberal are they in granting extensions?**  On one extreme, maybe they only grant it for emergency situations; on the other, maybe they usually always grant it if you pay the BWP500 and give the listed documents.

(Combining my personal experience and research, different countries can have *very* different overall dispositions on this kind of thing, so I am looking for experience which is relevant specifically to Botswana.  I've found it harder to find this sort of info for Botswana than for other countries, as it's not very populous or, it seems, heavily travelled.)